# colorPrimary or primaryColor?

Tags: android, colors, material-design, user-experience, material-components

Everywhere on the web I see uses of `colorPrimary` until I stumbled across Google's very own [Color Tool](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=1) where they use:

```
-<resources>

<color name="primaryColor">#303f9f</color>

<color name="primaryLightColor">#666ad1</color>

<color name="primaryDarkColor">#001970</color>

<color name="secondaryColor">#fdd835</color>

<color name="secondaryLightColor">#ffff6b</color>

<color name="secondaryDarkColor">#c6a700</color>

<color name="primaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>

<color name="secondaryTextColor">#000000</color>

</resources>
```

Once you export your picks.

So what is the correct convention? Also, would it affect the Material Components colors of widgets?

Comment: Personally, I prefer this as standard convention `colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent` and I don't see any reason why it would affect/ conflict the Material Components widget colors.

Answer (score 3):

1.If you define a color in `res/values/colors.xml`, then you can use any name on your own, the same when you create a variable in your Java/Kotlin class.

- *primaryColor*
- *colorPrimary*
- *primary_color*
- *color_primary*

An example from Android Developer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
   <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

2.If you create a custom styles/themes which extends from Android styles/themes, then you must use name that defined by Android.

```
// colors.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#008577</color>
    <color name="primary_dark_color">#00574B</color>
    <color name="color_accent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>

// styles.xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, in *styles.xml*, 3 attribute names, `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, `colorAccent` has been defined in parent theme, so you must use the same name because you want to override it.

In *colors.xml*, you can use any name that you think it make sense in your app.

Back to your questions:

> So what is the correct convention?

There is no standard convention in this case, but from Android Developer, you just give a name for the color, no need to add *color/Color* as a prefix or suffix. Because we usually put all app's colors in `res/values/colors.xml`, and each item is inside a color tag.

> Would it affect the Material Components colors of widgets?

It does not.

Comment: Your second point is what I don't understand. I extend from MaterialComponents.DayNight, so I would have to use the same item names. However Google's very own tool is using different names.

Comment: @PIXP When extending from a theme, you usually want to override some attributes in that theme, such as text color, button size, background, etc., then you must use the same item names (which defined in that theme). If you use another name, it does not affect to your app. Google is not **always** right. You can see this link. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same, check out
[Themes versus Styles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#versus)